# Using Multilayer Perceptron (MLP) to categorise images and its performance

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am new to Machine/Deep learning area!

If I understood correctly, when I am using images as an input,

the number of neurons at input layer = the number of pixels (i.e resolution)

The weights and biases are updated through back-propagation to achieive low as possible error-rate.

**Question 1.**

**So, even one single image data will adjust the values of weights & biases (through back-propagation algorithm), then how does adding more similar images into this MLP improve the performance?**
(I must be missing something big.. however to me, it seems like it will only be optimised for the given single image and if i input the next one (of similar img), it will only be optimised for the next one )

**Question 2.**

If I want to train my MLP to recognise certain types of images ( Let's say clothes / animals ) , what is a good number of training set for each label(i.e clothes,animals)? I know more training set will produce better result, however how much number would be ideal for good enough performance?

**Question 3. (continue)**

A bit different angle question,
There is a google cloud vision API , which will take images as an input, and produce label/probability as an output. So this API will give me an output of 100 (lets say) labels and the probabilities of each label.

(e.g, when i put an online game screenshot, it will produce as below,)
[image: example]

Can this type of data be used as an input to MLP to categorise certain type of images? 
( Assuming I know all possible types of labels that Google API produces and using all of them as input neurons )

Pixel values represent an image. But also, I think this type of API output results can represent an image in different angle.

If so, what would be the performance difference ?
e.g) when classifying 10 different types of images, 
**(pixels trained model) vs (output labels trained model)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can help you with the "intuitive" picture.

First, it may be worth looking at convolution neural nets and deep learning and see how to handle images as input to reduce  number of weights. It will not be 1 weight per pixel.

Also, what exactly you mean by "performance"? That is not a well defined question. If you use 1 image, say a cat, do you mean by performance that you can identify cats in other pictures, or how well you are able to get close to your cat?

Imagine you have a table of 3 weights, 1 input and 1 output, and trained your network to have error of < 0.01, and the desired output is 0.5

```
W1    |  W2    | W3   | Output

0.1     0.2      0.05   0.5006
```

If you retrain the network, you may get a different

```
W1    |  W2    | W3   | Output

0.3     0.2      0.08   0.49983
```

Since the weights are way different, you can imagine that there are several solutions.

Then, if you add another input, you can imagine that some of those weights which worked for first solution will work for the second.

Then you add another input. Then subset of the solutions with 2 inputs will work for 3 inputs. Etc.

When you have enough unrelated or noisy inputs, you won't find a subset of weights which meet your error criterion. Either you need to add weights (more degrees of freedom) or increase the error target, or both.

Now, you have a learning rate when you train a network. Say you are doing online training (for each input you update the weights), not batch training (you find the error vector for a batch (subset) of the input and you update your weights based on that, 1 time for the batch).

Now, suppose your learning rate was 0.01 and weight of 0.1. Intuitively:

If, for the first input, the first weight had derivative of 5, then your weight has new value of 0.1 - 0.01*5 = 0.05

If you feed your next input, say the derivative was -5. That means that the second input "disagrees" with the first change, and tries to go back to 0.01

If the derivative for the second input was 5, that means that the second weight "agrees" with the first.

If you have 20 inputs, some will pull the value up, some will push the value down. You keep looping through the training and then the value will approach a value which most of the inputs agree on, hence minimizing the error caused by that weight.

For question 2:

My mathematical guts feel tells me you definitely need at least 2*weight number to have any meaning to the training, but you should make that at least 10x the number of weights for the least minimum amount to even make a conclusion about your network, unless you are not trying to guess something new (for example, for xor gate, you can probably get away with way less input than weights, but that is a bit long discussion)

Note:

With 1 image, you can rotate it, stretch it, mix it with other images... to create another images and increase your input set.

If you have a simple input like xor gate, you can create inputs like (0.3, 0.7) (0.3, 0.6) (0.2, 0.8)... to expand your training set.

For question 3:

This is equivalent to chaining google's network with a network you create serially, but training each part separately.

Basically: You have Pictures --> 10 labels input to your network --> your classification

The problem I see there is, you may not know all the possible outputs of google's classification. But say they are consistent,

Is your label same as one of the 10 labels? If so, use the given label. If it is a different type of label, you can use that API to simplify your network. What are the consequences or what is the performance?

That is beyond me. In neural nets, while they have good mathematical theories to tell us what they can do, many posed problems such as the one you asked require either a special mathematical analysis (perhaps get PhD on some insight related to that class of problems)  or, as most do, show empirical results.

Comment: After reading your answers, I still kind of feel like the model only will be optimised to the very last training input. Also, what is happening when I am putting images of different resolution ? Then the number of neurons would change as well as the no. of weights.

Comment: Yes, but if your learning rate is small enough, that would be insignificant. There is a whole literature out there on how to randomly select input, how to focus on weights more than others, ...

Comment: I think I understand question 3, I'll update the answer.

Comment: riiiight. Thanks! and backpagation only happens once for each input right? (although many weights/biases get changed )

Comment: In "batch learning", you sum all the changes of weights as 1 update value for input "batch" or "group", and update the weights per batch of input. If for 3 inputs your w11 changes by 0.9, -0.1, -0.2, you update w11 once for 0.6. Empirical results show that either online or small batches are better than using whole input as batch because using whole input as batch is guaranteed to get you to the nearest local minimum, while the others can get you the nearest local minimum, but can get you somewhere better too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can I change my third question a bit ?

Comment: Sure you can :)

Comment: Assuming I know all possible google API output labels ( say 1000 ) and their probabilities and use all of these as an input neurons. Then, would it have any better result than the original (without links) ?  The reason why I am asking this is because, as far as I know to train such model, the number of input neurons should be the same (i.e resolution), however I am trying to implement a website that takes any resolution images and classify into set of labels I have created.

Comment: What do you mean by "Better than the original (without links)"? Which is the original, and what are the links? Also, would you mind if your network's performance is "Similar" but not "better"? Based on your problem description, I would do same hack. The only way to know is to try it!

Comment: Oh I was just hoping if linking (i.e using Google API in the middle) method would produce a similar result as the original one (i.e just using image pixels as an input, without google API result)  performance does not matter as long as it produces some reasonable result ( say >70% ). Just wanna know whether my idea is stupid or not!